# What's the most reputation that anyone has earned on a single day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What's the most reputation that anyone has earned on a single day? Who earned it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On April 11th, 2018 the record was broken by [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani?tab=profile)
and now stands at **1705 in a single day**. That day he got seven bounties.

[image: screenshot of reputation earned that day]

Comment: damn, since that day he has also had 3 more days of gaining more than 1000 rep :O

Comment: ^ What's the point?

Comment: Wow, you're very focusing on this i can see, answered it the day after the record break...

Answer (score 83):

As of today, that record belongs to [David Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson) who earned 1550 rep on July 6th, 2013.

> [image]

[The full list can be found with this query.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110083/most-rep-gained-in-a-single-day)

Comment: Three +500 bounties by the Community user? Sure was a nice day :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yeah, looks like someone sacrificed himself to perform this noble action. Or just a rage quit.

Comment: It's not until #16 that the person was rep-capped. Wow, that's surprising.

Comment: If you'd like to know the story: a user asked on Meta (in a since deleted question) whether there was a way to get rid of his reputation (I got the impression it was part of a ragequit). I suggested he could give it away in bounties instead, up to 1500 in a day- he was not aware that one could place bounties on other people's questions. To thank me for the information he ended up choosing me as the first recipient. Nice work if you can get it.

Comment: Aha, a variant on the "serial upvote" theme.  There should really be a bot that reverses this!  ;-)

Comment: For the record: number two is [James Holderness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2334192/james-holderness) with 1235 rep on July 23 2013.

Comment: @DavidRobinson if the user deleted himself, how is it possible that Community awarded your specific answer with the bounty, and with the full bounty amount? Another user gave up his rep before deleting himself in the same way, [but I only earned half the bounty amount](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1856499/revisions), because the user wasn't around to select my answer, Community automatically awarded it to me for being the top-voted new answer that was posted after the bounty started.

Comment: @Cupcake: The user awarded the bounty and selected the answer before (long before, if I recall correctly) he was deleted. I'm guessing that Community gets credit for bounties from deleted users.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I know you weren't entirely serious, but my initial thoughts went in the same direction. It's somewhat different because in this case, the user has to give up rep, which is not the case for serial upvotes. But once they decide that they want to get rid of their rep anyway, targeting a single user with bounties looks very much like the more standard serial upvote to me.

Comment: The list should actually be called "The Badass list"

Comment: [Gordon Linoff](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035) holds the record for most reputation earned in a day without receiving any points from a bounty, earning 680 points on 2014-02-12, including a ridiculous 32 accepted answers. Impressive.

Comment: @dano how you know this? Is there any search query?

Comment: @CalvT Seems like those are all self-accepts. Which don't count.

Comment: @Mysticial hmm thanks, the query is flawed then, as it clearly shows the guy in forth place with the rep mentioned

Comment: @CalvT The query is definitely not perfect. Not sure I'd have the time to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm guessing the reason is that you automatically take accept votes to be 15 rep, while some are actually the 2 you get for accepting an answer. Not sure how you could fix that, or if it's worth the effort