# What is a rage quit?

Tags: discussion, terminology

In this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267557/whats-the-most-reputation-that-anyone-has-earned-on-a-single-day?cb=1) the term "rage quit" is used by quite a few people. I couldn't find a formal definition on Stack Overflow or Google.

What is a rage quit? What is the normal cause of a rage quit?

Comment: Its typically two words.  [Range Quit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ragequit) from Urban Dictionary (yep, that great source of... well, lets call it knowledge for the time being).

Comment: It just means quitting in rage, while probably engaging in destructive behavior to better spread the misery. The damage caused by this will be reversed, partly automatically, partly manually.

Comment: From the über-meta: [What does it mean to ragequit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171581/what-does-it-mean-to-ragequit)

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHamidi! I wasn't aware of the über-meta.

Comment: "Not *another* downvote **again**! That Is IT! U SUCK!! IM OUTA HERE!!!" I *have* seen a few vowing "never ever" to come back to SO. It'd be interesting to know if, and how many, actually still did. Unfortunately, sentiments of this kind are usually expressed in comments or already-deleted posts ...

Comment: @MichaelT: Probably just a typo, but it's "Rage Quit", not "Range Quit".

Comment: @RetoKoradi ahh... the irony of a typo in a comment when correcting a typo.  Alas... *range* quitting must then be when you start singing "Home home on the..." and then stop.

Comment: @Jongware Back in the day such dramatic departures were called "goodbye cruel world" posts, at least in the places I used to frequent.

Comment: The normal cause of a ragequit is rage.

Comment: This used to be known as taking your marbles and leaving.  And maybe 15 years later taking your football and leaving.

Comment: Also see [Know Your Meme: Rage Quit](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rage-quit)

Comment: @HotLicks We were denied the opportunity to Rage Quit marbles because apparently, "Marbles are eye size. They're a definite no-no!" :|

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's mostly used in the gaming community to describe the act of someone leaving groups, clans, dungeons, or games out of anger.

A classic "Rage Quit" situation would be someone who dies in a game, perceives it as someone else's fault (or feels cheated) then leaves.

In the context of Stack Exchange, it's mostly related to someone rage quitting because they are angry about a post or comment and just want to stop being a part of the community, therefore leaving in a burst of anger, downvoting posts for the sake of downvoting, insulting people in comments, and/or unaccepting answers to questions just to annoy/harm others.

Example: As I am being downvoted for giving an answer that does not directly relate to Stack Exchange, I will create irrelevant questions, downvote answers and delete my account.

Comment: Rage quitting involves more than just quitting. It usually involves (trying) to delete all your posts and / or vandalising them. I know of at least one case where the quitter unaccepted all accepted answers on his questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is right, see for example [Why can't we delete more than five answers in a day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203195/165773)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The network oscillated on that day...

Comment: In Quake Live there is a command "/ragequit" which displays "<player> ragequits". It is popular because ID Software are the creators of "Quake Live" and also "Rage" therefore "rage quit".

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio I'm pretty sure the term *"ragequit"* predates "Rage"... :-/ Quake made it fashionable but it's origin is in the IRC chat rooms of the mid 90s early 00s.

Comment: internet relay chat chat

Comment: I don't think a "rage quit" necessarily entails a lot of negative behavior. You could quit out of rage but not scorch the earth on the way out. Of course, these types of "rage quit" are completely indistinguishable from somebody just stopping using the site for some other reason and so aren't particularly noteworthy.

Comment: @Lankymart I do so miss slapping people around with a large trout! mIRC <3

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wise guy *yawn*

Comment: @Gareth: `/xyzzy`

Comment: In gaming terms, it usually means a lot of swearing at the other team, throwing a controller and/or headset, and shutting off your console/pc.  You get so upset that you can't even try something else in the same context.  See also: Call of Duty.

Comment: @MattBurland But would that then be a "rage quit", as the term is understood? Just because it is composed of the same words, it doesn't follow that "quit out of rage" and "rage quit" are synonyms. I think "rage quit" implies at least making your rage obvious to the community/situation you're quitting, and not in a polite "I've decided to go and make a cup of tea instead" kind of way.

Comment: @IMSoP: Nope, I disagree. "Screw you guys. I'm going home". There, I just rage quit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in general use, a "rage quit" is as simple as abruptly leaving without comment. (IE: Starcraft quitting without a "gg", or WoW leaving with no comment after a wipe, etc.) It at most implies a lack of courtesy, not necessarily some sort of retaliatory behaviour. But, since there is no "goodbye" etiquette on SO/SE, I guess the "lack of courtesy" part is then interpreted to be vandalism and other similar misbehaviour. Technically, though, a person who gets angry and leaves the site forever (or even just for some time) is "rage quitting".

Comment: In gaming terms it just means that the person quit in anger as opposed to some other reason like boredom or real-life issues. It can even be inferred when nothing at all is said before quitting: "I haven't seen Bob online since he disconnected after that botched raid. Must have rage quit. I don't know what the term rage quit implies here. There's aren't as obvious places to express rage here, so it probably won't be noticed unless some sort of vandalism occurs.

Comment: AKA: Childish behavior.

Answer (score 6):

I had a massive rage quit a few years back. I was happy to quit quietly, but got into a rage when I couldn't delete my account. Of course I came back, but never really felt the same again.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/52458/dead-account

Comment: This is when you got pushed over the edge? "Ok - Im going to delete my account. –  Dead account Oct 7 '10". Rather civilized, compared to what I've seen so far. More of a 'huff resignation' actually.

Comment: GRRR!!! Right I'm deleting this account too. Just can't take the abuse any more... well, maybe later.

Comment: It's nice you came back :)