# Serial unaccept

Tags: discussion

I saw a reputation change due to an unaccept in my activity tab, explored by curious to know if any better answer posted, but eventually saw this serial unaccept pattern. Maybe he felt bad for the user removed 60 points for him & pushed him to this decision.

[image]

What will happen in this scenario? Is there a system in place to alert Moderators?

Comment: @yivi If that were a screenshot of his own profile, yes.  If it's a screenshot of someone else's profile, it doesn't mean that.

Comment: no.. when he accepts the answer he ll get +2.. that got reverted

Comment: @yivi Sure you can.  The only thing not shown is the -1 from your own downvotes, and the corresponding +1 when they're removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New phenomenon: Rage Unaccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166048/new-phenomenon-rage-unaccepting/166098#166098)

Comment: It is rage-quit pattern, not enough rep to do any real damage.  Having a sock account destroyed or a post downvoted can easily trigger it.  The moderators can't do anything about it, consider that an accept vote from such a user probably isn't that reliable anyway.

Comment: @Servy yes exactly, too bad the correct answer was deleted from that question though...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270072 And here's another rage-quit pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8074991/?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Just flag for mod to look into. I know of at least one case where a user was suspended for doing this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This was someone attempting to delete all their content from the site. I'm guessing this was motivated by what we did on January 15. They also had vandalized a number of their posts and had attempted via suggested edits to destroy the answers that others had left. Looks like they didn't want their code to remain on the site.

When you see this happening, flag us and we'll try to roll back any deletions and block them from further action. In this case, I accelerated their deletion request and made it so they won't be able to come back easily.

Comment: For the benefit of the unenlightened/forgetful, what happened on January 15?

Comment: @JoeC - See the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Cheers.