# Is there such thing as serial unupvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes, serial-voting

There is a serial down-vote and serial up-vote. I've always wondered if there is such thing as serial unupvote.

I mean, when you go to a user's profile, go through their questions/answers and remove your upvotes. Even if you can't remove the upvote due to the time the post was upvoted, you simply edit the question/answer and remove your upvote.

I've never came across such thing before, but I am wondering that since you are not upvoting or downvoting:

1. Can the system detect this and reverse it?
2. Is this also breaking SO rules just like serial upvoting and downvoting?

Comment: Well, there's a time limit after which you can't change your votes, so I would think this would happen less frequently.

Comment: Afaik, mild voting fraud corrections can show up as multiple unupvotes, appearing to be cast at the exact same time.

Comment: Similar things have happened before when people rage quit. They go through and un-accept answers to try and delete all their content. If they are editing posts just to remove an upvote, that might be considered fraudulent. I'm not sure what scenarios would be 'valid' where you would edit someone else's answer that you had previously upvoted such that it now deserves to have your up vote removed or changed to a downvote.

Comment: _"you simply edit the question/answer and remove your upvote"_ Not so simple for <2k rep users

Comment: @AndréKool I've seem someone with low rep edit my post before and added some nonsense to it. The Edit was approved and the upvote was gone just after that. A user could pretend that the Edit is adding more details to the post... Although this event is not why I asked this question. I just want to know if this is a problem on SO and if the system can also detect and reverse it

Comment: @HansPassant If that's the case then it looks like it can be detected and also be reversed. Not sure yet. Waiting for a full answer from anyone

Comment: Hard to guess what you mean, it is *because* of a reversal.  Show us a concrete example please.

Comment: Kinda related: [serial unaccept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364870/serial-unaccept)

Comment: It's possible for this to occur... but the likelihood of it is rather small, and the damage it might cause isn't all that much in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: If one has serially upvoted and promply repents, is it better to serially unupvote immediately or wait for the script?

Comment: wait, if it's past the period of time where you could undo it.

Comment: I liked this question so much I went and upvoted all of your other questions, but then I changed my mind and took them all back ;)

Comment: There is no such thing as serial *unpvote* :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Editing a post just to remove your vote is abusing the system, especially if done in an obvious way and repeatedly.

I'm not aware of automated detection of this, but I'm sure a mod won't mind if you flag it.

If they can manage to do this while making appropriate edits as well, that would probably also be frowned upon (but perhaps not quite against the rules).

Comment: Editing to remove a downvote you realize was misguided is a good thing, unupvoting out of spite isn't nice.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh You shouldn't really be editing to remove misguided downvotes either, at least not often (although I personally think that's a flaw in the system).

Comment: Well, hopefully we generally try not to be misguided in the first place.

Comment: @Dukeling: I wouldn't sweat isolated cases of it, though of course it's a good idea to avoid making a habit of it and, as Félix says, to just vote carefully in the first place. But no I wouldn't raise a stink about a one-off mistake. Everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: There is no automated detection for this, but of *course* it's the kind of unusual action that calls for investigation if the edits themselves are bogus, bump edits. Anything that *really* stretches edits thin for what they were meant for is suspect in my book. If a user is making good edits in the process, then... I'd probably just drop them a reminder not to let their votes be biased by either their edits or the posts they're editing, as well as, again, to exercise their votes with greater care in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The difference with serial downvoting is that:

- retracting user has to have upvoted victim user many times, or else it's not serial, so the case is probably pretty rare.
- if retracting user edits a lot of victim user *then* retracts vote, the victim will figure it out quite easily and will be able to call the mods in and explain the (unusual) situation.

Cosmetic edits to retract a downvote are IMHO not a problem (doesn't harm anyone, even if it unnecessarily bumps the post, maybe something useful can be added to avoid annoying everyone), but this kind of edit to retract an upvote (or to downvote, but that's off-topic here) is clearly out of line. That could get the offending user suspended (well, it's still a minor offence compared to sock puppet voting fraud or spam), but at any rate the moderators cannot force the offender to upvote again, so the rep is lost (like when an offending user is removed).

That's (SO) life.

Comment: Note that cosmetic edit are frowned upon because it unnecessary make old post bumbed on top of posts, on main tag this could ne considered as very annoying, and I'm pretty sure that users won't let it pass.

Comment: yes, that bump issue, very true.

Comment: These points are very obvious.  The question is whether or not the current system detects it.  Which is an interesting curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

While possible and actually done in the past, this is unlikely to be frequent problem. The amount of visible traces such "edit and remove vote" action leaves will likely lead to quick flags from authors of posts that were edited to change vote. I would not expect it to be done by someone who plan to keep they account on SO anyway.

I don't know of and don't expect system to actually detect this exact scenario, but I expect it rather be detected by mods via flags due to traceable nature of this voting.

Even if this is single occurrence just against one post it is likely flag-able as to make edit that make post deserve removal of vote one likely would need to make post worse. If you see that happening on a post make sure it is not reasonable removal of the vote (i.e. turned out post actually wrong answer even if it looked ok) before flagging.

To be done on any reasonable scale one need to have full edit privileges to perform that. If person tries to do that it is likely due to rage-quit and in this case attempt to remove votes is likely to be paired with removal of own content. Mass removal of own posts will trigger automatic ban to my knowledge and likely stop use from further altering of content. Even if they get caught by regular flags there is a good chance for them to collect enough of flags to hopefully float to top of moderator flag queue quickly.