# Strange serial "un"upvote

Tags: discussion, upvotes, serial-voting

Today, I have noticed a *funny* phenomenon as I got a lot of un-upvote in a short time period.

[image]

I don't really care about the rep I am losing, but I am wondering why it's happening?

1. Is there someone who suddenly starts *hating* me and went to un-upvote as many answers as he could (where there is an edit done after their upvote)?
2. Is this related to some sock puppet accounts? Yesterday I got some *user removed*, so there is probably a relation.
3. A rage quit of someone who wants to remove all their upvotes? For sure someone active in the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag.

I suspect it's (3), but maybe there is another reason.

I came across this question: [Is there such thing as serial unupvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365294/8620333) but it was a theoretical one and there is no edit done to any of my answers.

Again, my concern is not to get back the upvotes or the reputation, but I am curious to know what can be the reason of such phenomenon.

Comment: These do indeed look like manual removals of upvotes, rather than any sort of automatic voting fraud correction. Kind of curious, but probably not a cause for alarm.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought it is not possible to retract the vote on old questions without an edit or did something change (really curious)?

Comment: @CodyGray so it's the (3) then? someone trying to, probably, remove all his upvotes and probably trying to later delete his answers/questions?

Comment: @OlegValter I edit my old answers a lot, so there is a chance to be able to remove votes from many of them.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - so, you say if a user cast a vote during revision 1, you then edit the post to revision 2, they can indefinitely retract the upvote, am I correct? That is an important info to keep in mind going further if so. All your edits seem to be done in 2019

Comment: Could be. Not sure what the motives are, and it seems a waste of time to try and guess. If they do try to do something harmful, like delete all of their questions, then we should get an automatic moderator flag. If we don't, then do feel free to let us know. Rage quitting in the sense of deleting all your posts is not allowed here. But no objections to rage quitting by removing all your upvotes for that Temani guy. :-p

Comment: @Oleg Yes, that's correct. The concept makes sense if you think about it: while revision 1 might have been worthy of a *vote, revision 2 might have changed the content so it's no longer worthy of a *vote, or even worthy of a !*vote. (I hope my impromptu genericization of upvote/downvote made sense there.)

Comment: @CodyGray - thank you for confirming this - I agree that this makes sense, just good to know that editing a post results in it being unlocked and one is elegible to change their mind if they, for example, find an old post during cleanup that was changed to a more/less acceptable state a long time ago.

Comment: @CodyGray I imagine it's still possible to delete all of ones post without anyone noticing, if done slowly enough.

Comment: It isn't, @Scratte; the system should notice that. Unless, perhaps, none of your posts have received any upvotes. And even then, it would probably still notice. A moderator just might not care.

Comment: @Scratte Also accepted answers/questions with answers cannot be deleted.