# Add option to delete all comments with a single click instead of deleting them one by one

Tags: feature-request, comments

Recently I was deleting my old comments and noticed that currently there is no way to delete all of the comments with a single click. Instead currently I have to click on each of the comments which redirect me to the post and then I have to deleted that comment.

This is very tedious and inconvenient and so I want to users should be able to delete all of their comments with a single click.

I want this feature as there is already a manual way of deleting the comments but when doing so manually it is very tedious and so automating the same task can make this easy and less inconvenient. For example, a person using a particular browser is able to delete browsing history either by selecting one item at a time or by clearing it altogether which saves a lot of time and effort. And I expect the same from this feature(for comments only).

---

Additional things like giving users an option to select a date range from which the comments will be deleted can also be added.

Comment: Why? How does this feature request _improve_ Stack Overflow?

Comment: Erm, please don't just delete all comments. That might leave broken comment chains that need additional cleanups. Evaluate the context of the comment then delete it and anything else that needs to go. You can also modflag to clean long comment sections. Also, maybe the post under which the comment is might need to be updated.

Comment: @Cerbrus Because it helps automates a task that is already manually possible.

Comment: Do you meant deleting all your comments across all questions and answers? This seems quite destructive.

Comment: Whilst circumventing any and all sanity checks, and context checks as VLAZ mentioned. How is that "better"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, only a particular site's like stackoverflow comments

Comment: @JasonLiam it's also already manually possible to change your theme from light to dark and back. But I don't think a feature that automates flickers rapidly between the two few times a second would improve the site. The justification needs a tad more than "I can already do it"

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, now I want "Ravemode" next to my light and dark modes...

Comment: @JasonLiam "only a particular site's like stackoverflow comments" Honestly, I was already taking that as implied since otherwise it would be *even more* ridiculously destructive. Deleting all your comments on an entire SE site still  wouldn't count as deserving an "only"  by me.

Comment: @Cerbrus It is better because it automates a manual process.

Comment: Quality over quantity. "Faster" isn't necessarily "better". You're gonna have to come with a more convincing argument than that.

Comment: `setInterval(()=>document.body.classList.toggle('theme-dark'), 100)` ***UNTZ UNTZ RaveMode UNTZ UNTZ!*** Thank me later. (Obviously only works on sites with darkmode)

Comment: You've brought up "automating a manual process" as an explicit goal, as though that's always good– have you considered that the process is manual on purpose, _specifically_ to prevent what you're trying to do? While comments are commonly recognized as temporary, they're still content, and they still contribute to the context of posts (sometimes in a really important way!). Giving any user the ability to wipe out all of their comments unilaterally is way too much power to wield freely. Besides, even deleted users' comments stay around after the user is gone; we like keeping content around here.

Comment: @JasonLiam - please re-read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267629/what-is-a-rage-quit. You may want to clarify your intent right now before your account is locked out network-wide.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Why do you think I want to quit using a stackoverflow's community member? I have learnt a lot using this site and I''ve no intention of quit using this site as opposed to what you're trying to imply/suggest.

Comment: @JasonLiam bulk deletion of content is the main indicator of rage-quit. You are clearly asking for a feature to make it easier for you. Whether you are rage-quitting or not is somewhat irrelevant - an account showing such pattern of action can be locked out till things are sorted out. You may as well clearly spell out your actions (and most importantly the reasoning) before your account is locked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You can misinterpret my question however you like. I've already mentioned the reason I want this feature in my previous comments which is that doing this manually is very tedious and inconvenient and so i want an automated way of doing this. I've added the same reason in my updated post. It's like the user not being allowed to clear their browsing history all together. If their is an option to delete the item in the browsing search history one by one then there should be a way to delete all browsing history in one go.

Comment: Comments are not just your history. While not on the same level as questions and answers, many comments hold valuable information which needs *manual* intervention to identify and preserve. Indiscriminately deleting them is quite different from deleting your local, private data.

Comment: This is a signal. Potentially you are actually writing too many comments and should contain yourself a little more. Then this won't be as problematic since there will be less in need of cleanup. Are you sure you are up to speed with the rules surrounding making comments? Do you know what they are for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### We require users to manually review content they wish to delete

If a user concludes, after reviewing them *in the context of the post*, that each and every comment they have posted is no longer needed, they can in fact delete them from the post.  However, that review is *required*.  **We do not allow bulk deletion of content** by policy; attempts to do so may be, and often are, reversed by moderators*.  It is not possible to manually delete all comments *without viewing them in context*, and therefore we will not provide an automated way to do so, either.

---

<sup>* Generally, we are reversing the deletion of posts, rather than comments, but the same general analysis would apply to deletion of comments; this just hasn't really come up.</sup>

Answer (score 25):

I don't think there should be a delete all.

Yes, comments are generally considered disposable, but deletion of content should be something that requires review, not one button to delete them all. If anything, I'd opt instead for ways that make the process easier, like multi-select from the post page (not your profile)

Comment: It would also be quite destructive if someone like me decided to just nuke 23k comments. While most of them are probably no longer needed, it's still quite a destructive action to take. They're not all useless.