# Query gives wrong result of most reputation points gained in a single day

Tags: discussion, voting

Here is a query:

[Most reputation points gained in a single day.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110083/most-rep-gained-in-a-single-day)

[image]

As I note that the number 4. `ThomasReggi earn 1098 Reputation`, but after checking their reputation points it has not. The below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267557/3933332

Comment: Please don't destroy the content of your question. Also don't include answers in your question.

Comment: @Rizier123 My Question is different just I place wrong detail now you can see.

Comment: @Rizier123 first of all remove flag because it is different question.

Comment: Exactly, you asked a different question now than your original question. Also since only number 4 doesn't seem to be correct your question isn't why the query doesn't work, but more about what happened with number 4.

Comment: @Rizier123 now you understand my question.and also upvote if you understand the problem.

Comment: I think possibly it's taking all the "accepts" to be 15 rep, rather than 2 rep (which is what you get when you "accept" an answer to your question (and also doesn't seem to have the same immunity to the rep cap?).

Comment: @TZHX it is getting +2 because this user has accept the answer But also this user has accept answer by of all question in one day that's why ?

Comment: Generally, if you come to a forum asking "why doesn't this SQL produce the expected result", you'd be expected to at least read the SQL and understand it, and usually to have written it yourself.

Comment: @TZHX now what is the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

That query doesn't take into account that users don't receive 15 reputation points when accepting their own answer on their own question.

I've [edited](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482263/most-rep-gained-in-a-single-day-with-self-accepts-correctly-counted) the query to do this, but it's very heavy-handed having to add an additional left join to the Posts table. I'm not familiar enough with SE's schema to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Accepting self-answers does not yield 2 rep AFAIK.

Comment: @Fréd You are correct. I'm not sure if this is a change, or just my piss-poor memory.